# Python script cannot capture all TCP packets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I have a python script to capture all incoming TCP packets and showing its hex data.

My problem is that not all packets are capture.

Here is a MWE.

```
import os
import socket
import ssl
import threading
from datetime import datetime
 
def num2hexstr_halfbyte(x):
    if x >= 0 and x < 10:
        return str(x)
    if x >= 10 and x < 16:
        return chr(ord('A') + x - 10)
    return '?'
 
 
def num2hexstr_1byte(x):
    return num2hexstr_halfbyte(x // 16) + num2hexstr_halfbyte(x % 16)
 
 
server_address = ''
server_port = 7010
verbose = True
 
server_info = (server_address, server_port)
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(server_info)
server_socket.listen(100)
 
while True:
    client_conn, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    data = client_conn.recv(10240)
    client_conn.close()
    print(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    print('incoming address:', client_address)
    print('data part received of length:', len(data))
    if(len(data) >= 2):
        print('data[0-1]:', num2hexstr_1byte(data[0]), num2hexstr_1byte(data[1]))
    print('')
```

The result is

```
28/06/2021 12:06:08
incoming address: ('192.168.1.101', 36612)
data part received of length: 2
data[0-1]: 05 91
 
28/06/2021 12:06:09
incoming address: ('192.168.1.101', 50726)
data part received of length: 2
data[0-1]: 05 27
 
28/06/2021 12:06:14
incoming address: ('192.168.1.101', 45320)
data part received of length: 2
data[0-1]: 05 31
 
28/06/2021 12:06:19
incoming address: ('192.168.1.101', 50285)
data part received of length: 2
data[0-1]: 05 27
 
28/06/2021 12:06:24
incoming address: ('192.168.1.101', 38492)
data part received of length: 2
data[0-1]: 05 39
 
28/06/2021 12:06:29
incoming address: ('192.168.1.101', 60799)
data part received of length: 2
data[0-1]: 06 06
```

The script only captures the packets with length 2. All of them are what wireshark shows them as `[PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1`.

This wireshark screenshot
[image]

corresponds to the first two capture

```
28/06/2021 12:06:08
incoming address: ('192.168.1.101', 36612)
data part received of length: 2
data[0-1]: 05 91
 
28/06/2021 12:06:09
incoming address: ('192.168.1.101', 50726)
data part received of length: 2
data[0-1]: 05 27
```

I cannot find packets number 21 and 22. What is wrong with the script?

Comment: maybe you should  move `server_socket.accept()` outside the while loop.and move `client_conn.close()`  to other condition.

Comment: @nay, I did but it does not work: https://pastebin.com/qWUVbsjB

Comment: did you close connection after `recv()`?

Comment: You accept a connection, read some data, then hang up (close) on the client.  Keep receiving until the client indicates it is done (client closes connection, you recv() no data).  Do you have the code for the client connecting to the server as well?  It's not a MWE without the client side.